# ffmpeg: How to list all possible video parameters for DNxHD dnxhr_lb profile?

Tags: ffmpeg, dnxhr

If I don't put accepted video parameters for DNXHD profile, ffmpeg will list all the possible parameters like this. And I find this very helpful.

```
[swscaler @ 0x539a420] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] video parameters incompatible with DNxHD. Valid DNxHD profiles:
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 175Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 24000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 25/1
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 365Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 50/1
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 60000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 115Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
[dnxhd @ 0x55afb60] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 240Mbps; pixel .....
```

Is there a way to get this list for DNxHD codec dnxhr_lb or other DNxHD profiles below?

dnxhd
dnxhr_444
dnxhr_hqx
dnxhr_hq
dnxhr_sq 
dnxhr_lb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNxHR profiles have simpler restrictions - only on pixel format and minimum frame size.

Accepted Pixel formats

**LB**:  YUV 4:2:2 (8-bit)
**SQ**:  YUV 4:2:2 (8-bit)
**HQ**:  YUV 4:2:2 (8-bit)
**HQX**: YUV 4:2:2 (10-bit)
**444**: YUV 4:4:4 or RGB (10-bit)

In addition, all HR profiles require the picture to be at least `256 x 120`.

Comment: That's great. because DNxHD was rather very strict. Thank you Mulvya!

Comment: Yeah it's playing back in vlc 3+, surprisingly. Probably you are right and nuke's reader just can't handle it. I'm going to remove my comments to keep it clean here. Thanks again @Gyan

Comment: @p2or Nuke doesn't support DNxHR - https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/appendices/appendixc/supported_file_formats.html?tocpath=Appendices%7CAppendix%20C%3A%20File%20Formats%7C_____0